# Weird event binding issue on FF and Chrome - only on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is on my plugin page on Git and I have two interactive demo in the web page. In one of the demo page, I have a small dialog that opens when you click on a div.

The weird issue is that this dialog is getting opened when I click on the top title that says **attrchange beta** . This happens only if the first click is on the title **attrchange beta**, clicking any other element in page fixes this issue.

The plugin page <s>http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/</s> [Fixed, use the below URL to see the problem]

http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/index_so_issue.html

Below is the code,

```
<!-- The title -->
<h1 id="project_title">attrchange <span class="beta" style="text-decoration: line-through;" title="Almost there...">beta</span></h1>

<!-- Main dialog that has link to the sub-dialog -->
<div id="attributeChanger">
  <h4 class="title">Attribute Changer</h4>
  <p>Listed below are the attributes of the div:</p> 
  <div class="attrList"></div>
  <div class="addAttribute text-right"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="add new attribute">add new attribute</a></div>
</div>

<!-- Sub-dialog -->
<div id="addOrmodifyAttr" title="Add/Modify Attribute">
    <h4 class="title">Add/Modify Attribute</h4>
     <p><b>Attr Name</b> <input type="text" class="float-right attrName"></p>    
     <p><b>Attr Value</b> <input type="text" class="float-right attrValue"/></p>
     <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
     <button type="button" class="float-right close">Close</button>
     <button type="button" class="float-right update">Update</button>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $attributeChanger = $('#attributeChanger');
var $attrName = $('.attrName', '#addOrmodifyAttr'),
    $attrValue = $('.attrValue', '#addOrmodifyAttr'),
    $attrAMUpdate = $('.update', '#addOrmodifyAttr');

//Handler to open the sub-dialog
$attributeChanger.on('click', '.addAttribute', function () {
    $attrName.val('').removeClass('nbnbg');
    $attrValue.val('');
    $('#addOrmodifyAttr, #overlay').show();
});
```

Comment: Did you check console for errors?

Comment: @AaronLS Nope, no errors. The demo works fine, everything is good.. just this issue on first click.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `var $attributeChanger = $('#attributeChanger');` - Updated the post and updated the other var's as well.

Comment: I don't think the behavior you're seeing is being caused by the code and markup you've quoted. I recommend creating a [short, self-contained, complete example](http://sscce.org) and posting it to the question (and also, optionally, to http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Did you happen to check that URL? I would have fixed it or found a work around if I have an understanding of how or why it is happening.

Comment: @Vega: The link to the plugin page itself isn't sufficient. 1. That will change, and so of course the question would become useless to anyone else in the future. 2. You need to narrow down the problem to the *minimum necessary* to replicate it. That's *your* job, not ours. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question I have to disappear, good luck with it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the CSS applied to your `#attributeChanger` div.

If you look at the CSS applied to it:

```
#attributeChanger {
    background-color: #FEFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #4169E1;
    color: #574353;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 10px;
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You'll notice that the position is `absolute`, and it's positioned over your logo.  So what you're clicking is actually your #attributeChanger div.

[image: #attributeChanger positon]

To fix it, you can hide `#attributeChanger` using `display: none;`, then use `$('#attributeChanger').show();` in jQuery when it comes into actual view.

Comment: ahh.. makes sense that `opacity:0` is the culprit., but do you know why it goes off on first click.. +1

Comment: @Vega your click handler in the demo code for "document" hides the changer by moving it up beyond the top of the page.

Comment: On click you are applying this inline style to your div - `<div id="attributeChanger" style="top: -100px; opacity: 0;">`

Comment: @Pointy - Yea.. Just noticed after reading [Karl's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16485762/297641) answer.. Thanks.

Comment: If it begins at `top: -200px` and `position: absolute` then why is it on the screen? Shouldn't it be off the top?

Comment: @LeeMeador - it's not off the screen, because the parent div `.inner` is set to `position: relative;`, which means that the absolute positioning starts at the bounds of `.inner` (which is below the header).

Answer (score 3):

The pop up is showing because this code is running:

```
 }).on('click', '.addAttribute', function () {
$attrName.val('').removeClass('nbnbg');
$attrValue.val('');
$('#addOrmodifyAttr, #overlay').show();
```

This is because the DIV with the class addAttribute is over the title DIV.

You can either move the 'addAttribute' DIV, or remove the last line of that onclick function.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you element is hover your title and detect the click on himself and open(i don't know why it open, i didnt examine your entire code). But when you click anywhere else, your code is changing his position so it is not over the title.

The easiest fix is to change you `#attributeChanger` CSS `top` to -100px (that's the value when you click on the document) OR add a `display : none`.

**EDIT :** Axel answer show what I mean by "element is hover your title".